# How many sequences of digits of length 11 exist such that each of them contains all digits (from 0 to 9)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

To make condition true let’s take 10 digits of a sequence (I will call them “first” later in post) and we will choose digit on each position such that there will be all digits from 0 to 9, it can be done in $10!$ ways (on first we can put all 10 available  digits, on second 9 (without the one that we have already used) an so on).

On the eleventh position we can put any of 10 digits.

Also you might notice that these “first” 10 digits can be chosen in 11 ways (${11 \choose 10}$)

Naive answer would be $10!\cdot {11 \choose 10} \cdot 10$

But it’s easy to see that we are overcounting (for example let’s say that we have chosen first ten elements of the sequence as “first” elements and let’s also say that currently we have such a sequence: 0123456789 9 (space is made to differentiate “first” elements and one element where we can put any digit). We can get absolutely the same sequence in case when we choose “first” elements as first nine elements of the sequence and the last element of a sequence, one of possible sequences is 012345678 9 9. It is obvious that sequences that we got in first and in second situations are the same, but how to prevent this double counting?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sequence is counted exactly twice, so you can just take the naive answer and divide it by $2$.

Or you could introduce a rule that says you can only add the second occurrence of a digit after the place of its first occurrence, not before. Then for each of the $10!$ permutations there is $1$ sequence where the final digit is repeated; $2$ sequences where the last but one digit is repeated etc., giving a total of

$\displaystyle 10! \sum_{n=1}^{10} n = 55 \times 10!$

Comment: Thanks! But is there a more “elegant” way to calculate amount of suitable sequences?

Comment: @math-traveler Can you describe what a more "elegant" method would look like ?

Comment: What you suggested in your edited answer seems more elegant to me, thx)

Answer (score 0):

First choose a number with occurence two. We have 10 choices. Then we have 11! ways to order it. But we are counting every sequence twice(since we assume order between twice occuring number). So the answer is 10 x 11!/2 = 5*11!.

Answer (score 0):

Put the $10$ distinct digits orderly in row in front of the row of  $11$ cells.

Start with picking the digit $0$ and choice where to put it:  you have $11$ choices;
pass to digit $1$ : $10$ choices for it;
and so on ...
to get a total of $11 \cdot 10 \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 11 \cdot 10 \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 11! $ choices.

One cell remained empty: you can choose one of the $10$ digits to fill it.

Suppose wlog you choose the $0$.   All the strings in which the initial $0$ was in position $n$ and the empty cell (second $0$) in position
$m$ will be undistinguishable from case in which we invert $n$ and $m$; thus a division by two.

In conclusion
$$
{{11!\; \cdot \;10} \over 2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the 10 digits, you can choose which one to repeat in 10 ways. Use the [Tao of BOOKKEEPER](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/recitations/MIT6_042JF10_rec15_sol.pdf) to count the ways in which the 11 symbols (one each + the repéat) can be arranged:

$\begin{align*}
   10 \cdot \binom{11}{1\;1\; \ldots \; 2}
     &= 10 \cdot \frac{11!}{1!\, \ldots \, 2!} \\
     &= \frac{10 \cdot 11!}{2} \\
     &= 5 \cdot 11!
\end{align*}$